# Sum from an Array of Hex values to compute Checksum not working

Tags: c#, hex, checksum

I have an array containing the following Hex Values:

> A8, 00, 00, 11, 01, 44, 33, 28, 0C, 15, 2B, 00, 28, FF, 00, 00, 00, FE, FF, 80, 7F, 00, 00, FF, 00, 00, 00, FE, FF, 80, 7F, 00, 00, FF, 00, 00, 00, FE, FF, 80, 7F, 00, 00, FF, 00, 00, 00, FE, FF, 80, 7F, 00, 00, FF, 00, 00, 00, FE, FF, 80, 7F, 00, 00, FF, 00, 00, 00, FE, FF, 80, 7F, 00, 00, FF, 00, 00, 00, FE, FF, 80, 7F, 00, 00, FF, 00, 00, 00, FE, FF, 80, 7F, 00, 00, FF, 00, 00, 00, FE, FF, 80, 7F, 00, 00, FF, 00, 00, 00, FE, FF, 80, 7F, 00, 00, FF, 00, 00, 00, FE, FF, 80, 7F, 00, 00, FF, 00, 00, 00, FE, FF, 80, 7F, 00, 00, FF, 00, 00, 00, FE, FF, 80, 7F, 00, 00, FF, 00, 00, 00, FE, FF, 80, 7F, 00, 00, FF, 00, 00, 00, FE, FF, 80, 7F, 00, 00, 0C, 00, 03, 35, 00, 00, 00

I need to comupte a checksum from them, **the result I know to be C5**.

I have been given the following, which I am only seeing as obscure hints as they are vague:

- the checksum is derived by summing the values, and also for the result to "use the furthest right most Byte in Hexadecimal"
- Least significant Byte of all Data summed
- Add Data 8bit wide

If you prefer this as Decimal:

> 168,   0,   0, 
>    17,   1,  68,  51,  40,  12,  21,  43,   0,  40, 
>   255,   0,   0,   0, 254, 255, 128, 127,   0,   0, 
>   255,   0,   0,   0, 254, 255, 128, 127,   0,   0, 
>   255,   0,   0,   0, 254, 255, 128, 127,   0,   0, 
>   255,   0,   0,   0, 254, 255, 128, 127,   0,   0, 
>   255,   0,   0,   0, 254, 255, 128, 127,   0,   0, 
>   255,   0,   0,   0, 254, 255, 128, 127,   0,   0, 
>   255,   0,   0,   0, 254, 255, 128, 127,   0,   0, 
>   255,   0,   0,   0, 254, 255, 128, 127,   0,   0, 
>   255,   0,   0,   0, 254, 255, 128, 127,   0,   0, 
>   255,   0,   0,   0, 254, 255, 128, 127,   0,   0, 
>   255,   0,   0,   0, 254, 255, 128, 127,   0,   0, 
>   255,   0,   0,   0, 254, 255, 128, 127,   0,   0, 
>   255,   0,   0,   0, 254, 255, 128, 127,   0,   0, 
>   255,   0,   0,   0, 254, 255, 128, 127,   0,   0, 
>   255,   0,   0,   0, 254, 255, 128, 127,   0,   0, 
>    12,   0,   3,  53,   0,   0,   0

and the Decimal `checksum is 197`

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

In answer to [RJM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4421782/rjm)'s question, I have essentially tried looping through the values and totalling the LSB and also the MSB. as follows:

```
int LSB = 0; 
int MSB = 0;
foreach (Byte value in byteArray) {
    LSB += (value & 1);
    MSB += (value >> 7);
}
//Expected Checksum is 197
//LSB == 52
//MSB == 60
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Essentially I have tried to sum the LSB and also MSB of each byte, such as: `int LSB = 0; 
int MSB = 0;
foreach (Byte value in byteArray) {
    LSB += (value & 1);
 MSB += (value >> 7);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully more information was provided to me and I can post the solution.

```
int chk = 0;
foreach (Byte value in byteArray) {
    chk += value;
}
chk = (chk & 255);
```

So, essentially I needed to sum all the bytes and then use the LSB of the result.